# How to implement support for different language data?

Tags: sql-server-express

For now it supports data only in English.

For example I have a `title` and a `description` column. I want them to be in Russian or Hebrew. But when I type in these languages, it converts it to question marks.

Any solutions?

Comment: This might be a place to start:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143311(v=sql.90).aspx.